# Draw a filled semi circle

Tags: ios, uiview, core-graphics

What's the best method to draw a filled (!) semi circle in a UIView? I played around with the CGContextAddArc function but it does not seem to provide the filling. Here's what I like to draw - two filled semi circles.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
CGContextBeginPath(gc);
CGContextAddArc(gc, 100, 100, 50, -M_PI_2, M_PI_2, 1);
CGContextClosePath(gc); // could be omitted
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(gc, [UIColor cyanColor].CGColor);
CGContextFillPath(gc);
```

Comment: I had to use the "CGContextSetFillColorWithColor" function instead of "CGContextSetFillColor". With that it works great. Thanks!

Comment: Define cg with `CGContextRef gc = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();` for this to work

Comment: You can also use UIKit to do this. Thats what I did. 

        let y:CGFloat = bounds.height / 2
        let x:CGFloat = bounds.width
        let c = CGPointMake(x, y)


var maskPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: c, radius: x, startAngle: -(CGFloat(M_PI_2)), endAngle: (CGFloat(M_PI_2)), clockwise: false)

        var maskLayer:CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.frame = self.bounds
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath
        
        
        self.layer.mask = maskLayer